# How to override module-newsletter in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, overrides, newsletter

How to override the subscribe.phtml form which is in vendor / magento / module-newsletter to add my input data and save it in my database table ?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Are you talking about `subscribe.html` or *subscribe.`p`html*

Comment: Do you want a new field in the newsletter subscription?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to override newsletter in theme than you have to add `subscribe.phtml` file in

> design/frontend/themename/theme/Module_Newsletter/templates/subscribe.phtml

Than you  have to add below code in your footer block or call phtml in your footer.phtml file

```
{{block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="static.newsletter" template="Magento_Newsletter::subscribe.phtml"}}
```

just do it and newsletter works properly

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Pavel Ivatsko you can save your data using event and observe

event.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="newsletter_subscriber_save_before">
        <observer name="newsletter_subscriber_save_before" instance="vendor-name\module-name\Observer\newsletterSubscriberSave" />
    </event>
</config>
```

newsletterSubscriberSave.php

```
use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class newsletterSubscriberSave implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $this->_request = $request;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $subscriber = $observer->getEvent()->getSubscriber();
        $params = $this->_request->getParams();

        if(isset($params['subscriber_name'])) {
            $name = $params['subscriber_name'];
            $subscriber->setSubscriberName($name);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```